# Get direction to location iOS 6 using longitude and latitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, mapkit

I am looking to use the directions from Apple maps in iOS 6 in my app.

I have seen a few examples of how to do this but I am yet to see how this can be done using the longitude and latitude coordinates of a point.

Basically my app is using longitude and latitude to place pins on a map view I would like to get directions to these locations.

Does anyone have an example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using an `MKMapItem` in iOS 6:
(Note that addressDictionary is a dictionary containing keys and values from an Address Book record - see Apple docs for more details)

```
// Create MKMapPlacemark out of coordinates and addressDictionary
MKPlacemark *placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:addressDictionary];

// Create MKMapItem
MKMapItem *destination =  [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark];

// Using iOS6 native maps app
[destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];
```